# Buffer return value and 32bit unsigned integer

Tags: javascript, node.js, hex, buffer, bmp

I have a class project where we're converting a bmp file to a buffer, manipulating the buffer, and writing it to a new file.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

The first two bytes return the characters "BM" when converted to utf-8 using

```
buffer.toString('utf-8', 0, 2);
```

And sure enough the octets "42 4d" return "BM" when converted.

In class we were told that:
`buffer.readUInt32LE(2)` would return the size of the file (according to the file header).

In this case it's 4 octets:
"66 75 00 00"

Which using the `readUInt32LE` returns the number "30054" and sure enough when I checked the number of bytes, this was the case.

What I'm trying to figure out is the series of operations I need to make in order to for "66 75 00 00" to become "30054"

Any clarification would be helpful!

EDIT: I needed to calculated the hex values in the other direction! "75 66" and not "66 75". Thanks Guido :)

Comment: (hint) open a calculator, try to convert 75 66 from hex to decimal....

Comment: that's 6675, i said 7566

Comment: Ahhhh :P That was the issue.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness